# Multiple webviews in phonegap projects

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I am new to phonegap platform. Have some queries plz help me out.

First of all my question is that "what exactly is cordova cleaver"? plz answer in layman language.

Second if somebody says "each module running through one main webview object" then does this mean that the app has only one webview.

Thanks,
Vishal.

Answer (score 0):

with cleaver you can change a native view to show html

If you want to use cleaver, you have to include cordova as a framework.

in the .dmg you have a pdf explaining the steps to include cordova as a framework and how to use it.
I supose you need cordova installed, because if you don't install it, you can't get the cordova.framework